# How to write hive query for Regex_extract

Tags: regex, hive

Input file : 400xxx$52568999x&^000x&^00002

I want to extract this file into one column as : 4005256899900000002

How can I do in Hive Regex_extract ?

Please can any one let me know .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Hive, but in regex terms, what you're asking to do is:

**Search:** `\D+` (any chars that are not digits)

**Replace:** empty string.

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/iA6wI1), see the Substitutions at the bottom.